# How to prevent use of variable after its value has been moved to another variable?

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2013

With the introduction of std::move in C++ you can get rid of unnecessary copies.  Problem is that although you can move the value out of a variable, you cannot prevent the rest of the function to still refer to that variable.

For example, suppose I call a function that returns a big vector, and then (after some more code) I want to move this vector into another variable, like this:

```
auto lotsOfBooks = getAllBooks();
if (lotsOfBooks.empty())
   return;
...
auto library = Library("National Library", std::move(lotsOfBooks));
```

After the move of the books container to the library, I don't want the rest of the code to refer to the `lotsOfBooks` variable anymore.  But I don't see a way to prevent this.

I know that in many cases you can simply put part of the function in its own nested block (putting them in curly braces), but this is not always possible.
In this case, the problem could be circumvented by using `std::unique_ptr<Library>` instead of `Library`, but memory allocations are not always wanted.

Is there a way to prevent usage of a variable after a specific statement/line (either using a compiler construction, a C++ construction, code-checking tool (like Lint), ...)?

Comment: Sometimes it makes sense to refer to `lotsOfBooks` later, for example when doing `lotsOfBooks = getInterestingBooks();`. That said you can `#define lotsOfBooks` after moving and `#undef lotsOfBooks` at the end of scope. If you make it a practice to do this every time you can catch accidental uses of moved-from variables.

Comment: `lotsOfBooks` is a valid, destructible object, and if properly implemented, it must allow you to use any method that has no preconditions. This usually includes assignment, for example. So you can retain it simply to assign something else to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can never prevent a programmer to write a wrong sentence somewhere in its code. What you can (with the help of the compiler) is :

- try to detect the most common errors
- do your best for such errors to be detected as soos as possible at run time (at least in debug of non optimised mode)

That is what happen with move in C++11. The original pointer is set to null, or the original container is emptied. It gives 2 nice consequences :

- destructor cannot break anything (delete on a null pointer is harmless, so is destruction of an empty container)
- any access to the old variable should immediately throw an exception : null pointer access/assignement, index out of range for a vector, etc.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested yourself, you can only limit the scope of the variable by putting it into an local block. There is no other way to prevent access to the moved variable.